# QRegExp match certain letters?

Tags: qt, qregexp

I'm working with DNA, RNA and protein sequences and `QRegExp` doesn't work for me to detect if
the sequence contains only certain characters.
For example unambiguous contains only acgt :

```
seq.contains(QRegExp("[gatc]"))
```

Doesn't work for me. How can I correct that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for whether the sequence contains characters **other than** `gatc`. You also shouldn't be using the deprecated `QRegExp` in Qt 5. So:

```
#if (QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0))
QRegularExpression invalid("[^gatcGATC]");
#else
QRegExp invalid("[^gatcGATC]");
#endif

if (seq.contains(invalid)) {
  qDebug() << "invalid sequence!";
  ...
}
```

Comment: I thought the op was looking for finding a sequence of single occurences having all elements (a sequence in this sequence). Possibly looking if subsequences exist being invalid by not having all 4 elements. I probably misread the question on second thought

Comment: @SebastianLange "to detect if the sequence contains only certain characters" Seems clear enough to me...

Comment: QRegExp invalid("[^GATC]",Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    if (seq.contains(invalid)) {
      qDebug() << "invalid sequence!";

    }

Answer (score 0):

by default [QRegExp](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) is case sensitive.

```
QRegExp ( const QString & pattern, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive
```

You should add the parameter to make it case insensitive.

Comment: i know the problem not concerning CaseSensitivity .

Comment: QString seq("gactacgtccttacgaccaacggcgataaaaattgcccgcataagacaactttcgaggcg");

    qDebug()<<seq.contains(QRegExp("//[^gatc]"));

Answer (score 0):

**Misunderstanding the OP request.** This solution is for finding subsequences only containing all 4 elements once.

Since regular expressions cannot count occurrences, you will need to check for any possible match. Short example using 2 chars: AB and BA. AAABBBAAA to be checked. You will need to use QRegExp("(AB|BA)") since the expression cannot search for permutation. So looking for sequences having every element once, requires to have the regex check for (ACGT|ACTG|AGCT|....)

It would be easier to implement something like:

```
QString seq = "gactacgtccttacgaccaacggcgataaaaattgcccgcataagacaactttcgaggcg";
QMap<QChar,int> count;

void resetCounter()
{
  count[QChar('a')] = 0;
  count[QChar('c')] = 0;
  count[QChar('g')] = 0;
  count[QChar('t')] = 0;
}

bool checkCounter()
{
  foreach(count.values(), int val)
    if(val != 1)
      return false;
  return true;
}


resetCounter();
for(int i=0; i<seq.length(); i++)
{  
  count[seq.at(i)] = count[seq.at(i)] + 1;
  if(count[seq.at(i)] > 1)
  {
    resetCounter();
    count[seq.at(i)] = 1;
  }
  if(checkCounter())
  {
    //Found sequence
    count[seq.at(i-3)] = 0;
  }
}
```

Edit: Found small mistake. Have to set current element to 1 after resetCounter() being called